# How I can implement this hierarchy?

Tags: java

We have class animal on the top. Then we have subclasses mammal, reptile, fish and bird. Subclasses of this subclasses are lion, dog, snake, lizard, sprat, shark, dove and eagle.
This all are classes.  We need to make difference if the animals are terrestial, water or flying and also the water animals are 2 types: freshwater and saltwater. Also they can be water and terrestial for example. I thought about interfaces but maybe it isn't good because for birds for example we dont have what to implement like method. Maybe I can make it like variables in animal class and then in the constructors will this boolean variables. I am not sure how is the best way to implement this. can you help me ?

Comment: At least give some evidence of something you attempted.

Comment: you don't have anything to implement for birds? srsy? what about fly? flap wings? soar?

Comment: This is more of a thinking exercise. It's recommended to do on your own. Would help later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't make variables for an animal's traits, because those traits don't change (disregarding evolution).

Firstly, you need a decent book on object-oriented design, rather than asking us to help.  Take some initiative and do some research.

For the moment, how about just implementing some basic polymorphic boolean functions like `IsTerrestrial()`, `IsAquatic()`, etc...  Maybe make an enumeration for `AquaticType` that returns `None`, `FreshWater`, `SaltWater` or `Both`.  You override these methods at the highest level possible so that your subtypes don't have to worry.

For example, almost all fish are not terrestrial, so the subclasses of `Fish` should not have to implement this method (the `Fish` class should).  Likewise, most mammals are not aquatic.

This is all a bit subjective.  There are many ways to represent this information in a class hierarchy, but this should give you a start.